# Nancy Self Host and Static Content Files

Tags: c#, console-application, nancy, self-hosting

Am I right in thinking that if you create a self host nancy console app and want to serve up html,javascript and  css files that you have to go thru all these files (could be quite a few) and mark them all for copy to output directory.

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {

        Get["/"] = v =>  View["index.html"];
    }
}
```

This will not be found if the index.html file is in the project folder and is not marked copy to output on it's properties.

Comment: No spender you're wrong.

Comment: @Phill Yes I am! A postbuild event could do an xcopy or similar... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827024/copying-visual-studio-project-files-to-output-directory-during-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I stand corrected, I misunderstood the question.

Yes you need to set all static content to copy, however when I setup my project's (I can't copy paste an example for you at the moment), I just add a Build Event in the project file, or I setup a Build Task for the CI / deployment.

---

Nope, you don't need to mark every file individually.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content

You can mark an entire directory.

Alternatively, if you're using OWIN, you can use the Static Content middleware.

Something like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var fileSystem = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("....")
        };

        app.UseFileServer(fileSystem);
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you've misunderstood what OP is asking. They have made a (non-web) project where the executable is created by VS in the `/bin` folder and run. This means that (unlike in a web project) any content files must also be copied into the `/bin` folder by explicitly changing the properties for each one of these files to "copy to output directory". OP is asking if this property change can be automated in some way.

Comment: OH, I stand corrected. In that case I just copy as part of a build event in the project file or a build task on the CI.

Comment: Thanks for the info - so if I wanted to use a post build event what is the switch to preserve the file structure /t retains the file structure but does not copy files I want to retain directory structure and copy files?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found a workaround that others might find useful:

Instead of copying the files to the output directory on each build, I created a [directory junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) in it, targeting the original static-files directories.

This allows real-time editing of the static content in Visual-Studio (without the need to rebuild in order to copy the edited files to the output directory)

e.g. (Post-build command line):

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Web" md "$(TargetDir)Web"
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Web\Content" mklink /j "$(TargetDir)Web\Content" "$(ProjectDir)Content" 
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Web\Scripts" mklink /j "$(TargetDir)Web\Scripts" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts" 
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Web\Fonts" mklink /j "$(TargetDir)Web\Fonts" "$(ProjectDir)Fonts" 
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Web\Static" mklink /j "$(TargetDir)Web\Static" "$(ProjectDir)Web\Static"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Visual studio build events]

You can use Visual studio build events and add xcopy command like this:

```
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)\Views" "$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Views\*"
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)\Content" "$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Content\*"
```

when project is built xcopy gets executed and files are copied in output dir, so your selfhost exe can see that files.