# how to set image in Visual Studio C# Windows Forms with Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

So I'm trying to set a custom image for a form application I've made. The images I'm trying to target are in a folder called "Images" on the same level as my Solution file. The solution file is a C# windows forms (net core framework) solution. It's a basic form app that I want to display an image based on a users selection, however right now I get an unhandled exception everytime I try to set the image with this code:

```
picFood.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Images/burger.jpg");
```

The exact error is "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ../../Images/burger.jpg"

In another totally unrelated solution this works. Folder structure is the same. A folder called Images, on the same directory level as the .sln file holds the images there. They're in my solution explorer and everything. I've tried this with one "../" and no "../" as well so I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: The error is clear, the file is not found in the given path. Have you pasted the path into a windows explorer to see if the path indeed contains the specified file?

Comment: I guess my question lies in, is there a way to store the file in a subdirectory and call it without using the whole path of where it is?

Comment: If you set the properties of you image files to `Copy Always`, then you will find an `images` folder in the same folder as your EXE. Then you can just refer to it by `.\images\whatever.jpg`, and, when build a deployment package, everything is in the one place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files with relative paths are opened relative to the working directory of your application.

In this case, when launching from within Visual Studio, the default is the `bin` folder where the compiled application is put by default.

So if your binary is in `<project dir>/bin/Debug/App.exe` this path will resolve to `<project dir>/Image/burger.jpg`.
If you have changed something in your build configuration, or your application switches directory at runtime (e.g. via [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0)), this path may be different than you expect.

To understand your issue, I suggest you start looking at what your working directory is. You can obtain that in your code via [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0).
You can also resolve your relative path using [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-5.0).
Print these two values to see where your program attempts to load the file from.

Keep in mind that any image files you put in the solution/project folder will need to be copied with your binary if you want to use them.
To use relative paths without `..` you can copy them alongside your binary during compilation, see:
[VS2010 How to include files in project, to copy them to build output directory automatically during build or publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a) and [Copying Visual Studio project file(s) to output directory during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827024/copying-visual-studio-project-files-to-output-directory-during-build) for how to do that.

Comment: Yea I was getting the relative pathing incorrect. I also added them as resources in the resource folder as well. I had them previously in an Images folder, in the same spot as the now resource folder but the same location call ("../../Images/file.jpg") wasn't working, now with them in the resources folder it does work. obviously pointing it to the resources folder instead of the images folder, but it's fine now so I'm happy.